# PHP: HTML rendering small square box

Tags: php, html, special-characters

My page is rendering dynamic description (being picked from database) which is converting single quotes and double quotes to small square boxes wrapped around some strings:

[image]

I tried functions like `htmlspechialchars` or `html_entity_decode` but none of them worked.

Any help?

Comment: Without knowing your database structure and seeing your code, how should we help?

Comment: We need more information from you starting from your database structure and collation and moving on to your actual code.

Comment: I do not have access to database. so I am helpless in this regard too :(

Comment: The square characters indicate character sequences that are invalid for the character encoding you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It would actually be great to see some of your code to be able to know the right solution. Try to check these things:

- Check your database - is the data stored the right way?
- Check or set your encoding in the script where the data is output (use a .htaccess-file or meta-tags like the following)

**HTML**

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

If this doesn't help, please provide more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Never Mind. I have got solution by replacing the garbage/special characters.

```
    $search = array(chr(145),
                    chr(146),
                    chr(147),
                    chr(148),
                    chr(151));

    $replace = array("'",
                     "'",
                     '"',
                     '"',
                     '-');
    echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```